# Terrible performance using XGBoost H2O

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, h2o, xgboost

Very different Model Performance using XGBoost on H2O

I am training a XGBoost model using 5-fold croos validation on a very imbalanced binary classification problem. The dataset has 1200 columns (multi-document word2vec document embeddings).

The only parameters specified to train the XGBoost model were:

- min_split_improvement = 1e-5
- seed=1
- nfolds = 5

The reported performance on train data was extremely high (probably overfitting!!!):

```
Confusion Matrix (Act/Pred) for max f1 @ threshold = 0.2814398407936096: 
       A      D    Error    Rate
-----  -----  ---  -------  -------------
A      16858  2    0.0001   (2.0/16860.0)
D      0      414  0        (0.0/414.0)
Total  16858  416  0.0001   (2.0/17274.0)

AUC: 0.9999991404060721
```

The performance on cross validation data was terrible:

```
Confusion Matrix (Act/Pred) for max f1 @ threshold = 0.016815993119962513: 
       A      D    Error    Rate
-----  -----  ---  -------  ----------------
A      16003  857  0.0508   (857.0/16860.0)
D      357    57   0.8623   (357.0/414.0)
Total  16360  914  0.0703   (1214.0/17274.0)

AUC: 0.6015883863129724
```

I know H2O cross validation generates an extra model using the whole data available and different performances are expected.
But, could be the cause that generated too bad performance on the resulting model?

Ps: XGBoost on a multi node H2O cluster with OMP

```
Model Type: classifier
Performance do modelo < XGBoost_model_python_1575650180928_617 >: 

ModelMetricsBinomial: xgboost
** Reported on train data. **

MSE: 0.0008688085383330077
RMSE: 0.029475558320971762
LogLoss: 0.00836528606162877
Mean Per-Class Error: 5.931198102016033e-05
AUC: 0.9999991404060721
pr_auc: 0.9975495622569983
Gini: 0.9999982808121441

Confusion Matrix (Act/Pred) for max f1 @ threshold = 0.2814398407936096: 
       A      D    Error    Rate
-----  -----  ---  -------  -------------
A      16858  2    0.0001   (2.0/16860.0)
D      0      414  0        (0.0/414.0)
Total  16858  416  0.0001   (2.0/17274.0)

Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
metric                       threshold    value     idx
---------------------------  -----------  --------  -----
max f1                       0.28144      0.99759   195
max f2                       0.28144      0.999035  195
max f0point5                 0.553885     0.998053  191
max accuracy                 0.28144      0.999884  195
max precision                0.990297     1         0
max recall                   0.28144      1         195
max specificity              0.990297     1         0
max absolute_mcc             0.28144      0.997534  195
max min_per_class_accuracy   0.28144      0.999881  195
max mean_per_class_accuracy  0.28144      0.999941  195
max tns                      0.990297     16860     0
max fns                      0.990297     413       0
max fps                      0.000111383  16860     399
max tps                      0.28144      414       195
max tnr                      0.990297     1         0
max fnr                      0.990297     0.997585  0
max fpr                      0.000111383  1         399
max tpr                      0.28144      1         195

Gains/Lift Table: Avg response rate:  2.40 %, avg score:  2.42 %
    group    cumulative_data_fraction    lower_threshold    lift     cumulative_lift    response_rate    score        cumulative_response_rate    cumulative_score    capture_rate    cumulative_capture_rate    gain     cumulative_gain
--  -------  --------------------------  -----------------  -------  -----------------  ---------------  -----------  --------------------------  ------------------  --------------  -------------------------  -------  -----------------
    1        0.0100151                   0.873526           41.7246  41.7246            1                0.907782     1                           0.907782            0.417874        0.417874                   4072.46  4072.46
    2        0.0200301                   0.776618           41.7246  41.7246            1                0.834968     1                           0.871375            0.417874        0.835749                   4072.46  4072.46
    3        0.0300452                   0.0326301          16.4004  33.2832            0.393064         0.303206     0.797688                    0.681985            0.164251        1                          1540.04  3228.32
    4        0.0400023                   0.0224876          0        24.9986            0                0.0263919    0.599132                    0.518799            0               1                          -100     2399.86
    5        0.0500174                   0.0180858          0        19.9931            0                0.0201498    0.479167                    0.418953            0               1                          -100     1899.31
    6        0.100035                    0.0107386          0        9.99653            0                0.0136044    0.239583                    0.216279            0               1                          -100     899.653
    7        0.149994                    0.00798337         0        6.66692            0                0.00922284   0.159784                    0.147313            0               1                          -100     566.692
    8        0.200012                    0.00629476         0        4.99971            0                0.00709438   0.119826                    0.112249            0               1                          -100     399.971
    9        0.299988                    0.00436827         0        3.33346            0                0.00522157   0.0798919                   0.0765798           0               1                          -100     233.346
    10       0.400023                    0.00311204         0        2.49986            0                0.00370085   0.0599132                   0.0583548           0               1                          -100     149.986
    11       0.5                         0.00227535         0        2                  0                0.00267196   0.0479333                   0.0472208           0               1                          -100     100
    12       0.599977                    0.00170271         0        1.66673            0                0.00197515   0.039946                    0.0396813           0               1                          -100     66.6731
    13       0.700012                    0.00121528         0        1.42855            0                0.00145049   0.0342375                   0.034218            0               1                          -100     42.8548
    14       0.799988                    0.000837358        0        1.25002            0                0.00102069   0.0299588                   0.0300692           0               1                          -100     25.0018
    15       0.899965                    0.000507632        0        1.11115            0                0.000670878  0.0266306                   0.0268033           0               1                          -100     11.1154
    16       1                           3.35288e-05        0        1                  0                0.00033002   0.0239667                   0.0241551           0               1                          -100     0


Performance da validação cruzada (xval) do modelo < XGBoost_model_python_1575650180928_617 >: 

ModelMetricsBinomial: xgboost
** Reported on cross-validation data. **

MSE: 0.023504756648164406
RMSE: 0.15331261085822134
LogLoss: 0.14134815775808462
Mean Per-Class Error: 0.4160864407653825
AUC: 0.6015883863129724
pr_auc: 0.04991836222189148
Gini: 0.2031767726259448

Confusion Matrix (Act/Pred) for max f1 @ threshold = 0.016815993119962513: 
       A      D    Error    Rate
-----  -----  ---  -------  ----------------
A      16003  857  0.0508   (857.0/16860.0)
D      357    57   0.8623   (357.0/414.0)
Total  16360  914  0.0703   (1214.0/17274.0)

Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
metric                       threshold    value      idx
---------------------------  -----------  ---------  -----
max f1                       0.016816     0.0858434  209
max f2                       0.00409934   0.138433   318
max f0point5                 0.0422254    0.0914205  127
max accuracy                 0.905155     0.976323   3
max precision                0.99221      1          0
max recall                   9.60076e-05  1          399
max specificity              0.99221      1          0
max absolute_mcc             0.825434     0.109684   5
max min_per_class_accuracy   0.00238436   0.572464   345
max mean_per_class_accuracy  0.00262155   0.583914   341
max tns                      0.99221      16860      0
max fns                      0.99221      412        0
max fps                      9.60076e-05  16860      399
max tps                      9.60076e-05  414        399
max tnr                      0.99221      1          0
max fnr                      0.99221      0.995169   0
max fpr                      9.60076e-05  1          399
max tpr                      9.60076e-05  1          399

Gains/Lift Table: Avg response rate:  2.40 %, avg score:  0.54 %
    group    cumulative_data_fraction    lower_threshold    lift      cumulative_lift    response_rate    score        cumulative_response_rate    cumulative_score    capture_rate    cumulative_capture_rate    gain       cumulative_gain
--  -------  --------------------------  -----------------  --------  -----------------  ---------------  -----------  --------------------------  ------------------  --------------  -------------------------  ---------  -----------------
    1        0.0100151                   0.0540408          4.34129   4.34129            0.104046         0.146278     0.104046                    0.146278            0.0434783       0.0434783                  334.129    334.129
    2        0.0200301                   0.033963           2.41183   3.37656            0.0578035        0.0424722    0.0809249                   0.094375            0.0241546       0.0676329                  141.183    237.656
    3        0.0300452                   0.0251807          2.17065   2.97459            0.0520231        0.0292894    0.0712909                   0.0726798           0.0217391       0.089372                   117.065    197.459
    4        0.0400023                   0.02038            2.18327   2.77762            0.0523256        0.0225741    0.0665702                   0.0602078           0.0217391       0.111111                   118.327    177.762
    5        0.0500174                   0.0174157          1.92946   2.60779            0.0462428        0.0188102    0.0625                      0.0519187           0.0193237       0.130435                   92.9463    160.779
    6        0.100035                    0.0103201          1.59365   2.10072            0.0381944        0.0132217    0.0503472                   0.0325702           0.0797101       0.210145                   59.3649    110.072
    7        0.149994                    0.00742152         1.06366   1.7553             0.0254925        0.00867473   0.0420687                   0.0246112           0.0531401       0.263285                   6.3664     75.5301
    8        0.200012                    0.00560037         1.11073   1.59411            0.0266204        0.00642966   0.0382055                   0.0200645           0.0555556       0.318841                   11.0725    59.4111
    9        0.299988                    0.00366149         1.30465   1.49764            0.0312681        0.00452583   0.0358935                   0.0148859           0.130435        0.449275                   30.465     49.7642
    10       0.400023                    0.00259159         1.13487   1.40692            0.0271991        0.00306994   0.0337192                   0.0119311           0.113527        0.562802                   13.4872    40.6923
    11       0.5                         0.00189            0.579844  1.24155            0.0138969        0.00220612   0.0297557                   0.00998654          0.057971        0.620773                   -42.0156   24.1546
    12       0.599977                    0.00136983         0.990568  1.19972            0.0237406        0.00161888   0.0287534                   0.0085922           0.0990338       0.719807                   -0.943246  19.9724
    13       0.700012                    0.000980029        0.676094  1.1249             0.0162037        0.00116698   0.02696                     0.0075311           0.0676329       0.78744                    -32.3906   12.4895
    14       0.799988                    0.00067366         0.797286  1.08395            0.0191083        0.000820365  0.0259787                   0.00669244          0.0797101       0.86715                    -20.2714   8.39529
    15       0.899965                    0.000409521        0.797286  1.05211            0.0191083        0.000540092  0.0252155                   0.00600898          0.0797101       0.94686                    -20.2714   5.21072
    16       1                           2.55768e-05        0.531216  1                  0.0127315        0.000264023  0.0239667                   0.00543429          0.0531401       1                          -46.8784   0
```

Answer (score 0):

For the non cross-validation case, try splitting your data up front into training and validation frames.

I expect you will get a worse AUC for the validation case.

Although for highly imbalanced cases, sometimes you just need to go by the error rate for each class.

Since there are so many true negatives, that can dominate the AUC (vast majority of predictions are correctly predicting “not interesting”).  Some people will upsample the minority class in this situation using row weights to make the model more sensitive to them.